# Broadcast python objects using mpi4py

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, mpi, mpi4py

I have a python object

```
<GlobalParams.GlobalParams object at 0x7f8efe809080>
```

which contains various numpy arrays, parameter values etc. which I am using in various functions calling as for example:

```
myParams = GlobalParams(input_script) #reads in various parameters from an input script and assigns these to myParams
myParams.data #calls the data array from myParams
```

I am trying to parallelise my code and would like to broadcast the `myParams` object so that it is available to the other child processes. I have done this previously for individual numpy arrays, values etc. in the form:

```
points = comm.bcast(points, root = 0)
```

However, I don't want to have to do this individually for all the contents of `myParams`. I would like to broadcast the object in its entirety so that it can be accessed on other cores. I have tried the obvious:

```
myParams = comm.bcast(myParams, root=0)
```

but this returns the error:

```
 myParams = comm.bcast(myParams, root=0)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1276, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.bcast (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:108819)
  File "MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 612, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_bcast (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:47005)
  File "MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 112, in mpi4py.MPI.Pickle.dump (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:40704)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

What is the appropriate way to share this object with the other cores? Presumably this is a common requirement in python, but I can't find any documentation on this. Most examples look at broadcasting a single variable/array.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like an MPI problem; it looks like a problem with object serialisation for broadcast, which internally is using the `Pickle` module.

Specifically in this case, it can't serialise a `_io.TextIOWrapper` - so I suggest hunting down where in your class this is used.

Once you work out which field(s) can't be serialised, you can remove them, broadcast, then reassemble them on each individual rank, using some method that you need to design yourself (`recreateUnpicklableThing()` in the example below). You could do that by adding these methods to your class for `Pickle` to call before and after broadcast:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    members = self.__dict__.copy()
    # remove things that can't be pickled, using its name
    del members['someUnpicklableThing'] 
    return members

def __setstate__(self, members):
    self.__dict__.update(members)
    # On unpickle, manually recreate the things that you couldn't pickle
    # (this method recreates self.someUnpickleableThing using some metadata 
    # carefully chosen by you that Pickle can serialise).
    self.recreateUnpicklableThing(self.dataForSettingUpSometing)
```

See here for more on how these methods work
https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html